# Nested @input properties in angular

Tags: angular

I have three components with @Input properties with the same name.

The for the first child component everything works.

For the 2nd nested component the property change never fires.

However, when I change the name of the property that is bound everything works.

Is there some sort of issue when using nested @Inputs with the same property name?

Fails

```
  <app-available-funds-ledger [assignedTotal]="assignedTotal"

  ></app-available-funds-ledger>
```

Works

```
  <app-available-funds-ledger [assignedTotal]="differentPropertyName"

  ></app-available-funds-ledger>
```

Comment: And, if so, what's the exact error you're getting in the console? Can you create a StackBlitz the demonstrates what you're seeing?

Comment: No, you can name nested inputs the same.

Comment: Can you share more code? Are these 'nested' components actually children of the same parent? Do you use any @Output in components that affects the value of @Inputs? Please share more relevant ts and html codes.